# Array inside if conditional in javascript ?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
if( 5 > array ){
   alert('ok');
}
```

Can i do this in javascript ?

Comment: Have a look at [array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: What do you want from that condition? maybe to compare with an array size? it's just `5 > array.length`

Comment: are you trying to compare the array length?

Comment: Your question is not complete. What is your logic here `5 > array`?

Comment: i want to check if "5" is match with all values inside that array

Comment: I guess you want `array.every(val => 5 > val)`.

Comment: To answer your question: JavaScript allows you do that but it does not have the effect you want. To achieve what you want you should do what @torazaburo suggested.

Comment: ya maybe i give u a wrong example, for what i want to achieve. i ll fix my question.

Comment: Don't rewrite your question after people have answered the previous version. It's extremely rude. Instead, delete this question and post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple, use `.indexOf()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

```
var text ="abc";
var array = ['abc', 'def'];
if(array.indexOf(text) !== -1){
   alert('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this in JavaScript?

I don't know. Try it.

An `if` statement evaluates a single expression. If you want to evaluate multiple conditions, which is the case here, you have to write the multiple conditions.

```
if( 5 > array[0] && 5 > array[1] && 5 > array[2] && 5 > array[3]) {
  alert('ok');
}
```

Since that is not going to work well if you don't know the number of elements in `array` in advance, you could write a loop, looking for failing cases:

```
let ok = true;

for (const i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (5 > array[i]) continue;
  ok = false;
  break;
}

if (ok) alert('ok');
```

It turns out, though, that arrays have a built-in method to check to see if some condition holds for all elements, so we can write:

```
if (array.every(elt => 5 > elt)) alert('ok');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to check if an element(text) exists in the array, then this can be used

```
if(array.indexOf(text) !== -1){
   alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you sir :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var i = 0;
var num = 4;
for(i = 0;i < array.length;i++){
      if(array[i] == num){
            alert("OK")
      }
 }
```

> This can also be used but using the indexOf() function will be much faster